# Application with only one user admin without sign up part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I did all Michael Hartl tutorial's application, and now I would like to create my on one, a writer assistant to edit a book.

I want to have only one user in database and it will be the admin. In the menu, only a signin button to connect and begin writting the book.

I'm wondering how to do and what is the best way to put only one user in the database. As in the tutorial there is the sign up part.

I hope you understand what I mean, and sorry for my bad english

Thanks

Comment: why would you need a model for the admin if there will only ever be one?

Comment: I agree. You can manage it quite easily with a session and hardcoded username/pass combo, or with Rails basic_auth: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did want database manipulation/seeding

you could either
a) add a create statement in the seed.rb file

```
 admin_user = User.create!(first_name: "test",
                           last_name: "test",
                           password: "123",
                           password_confirmation: "123",
                           roles: ["admin"])
```

then from the command line within your project run

```
rake db:seed
```

b) From the command line run

```
rails console
```

This gives you a command line loaded rails environment.

Where you can execute

```
admin_user = User.create!(first_name: "test",
                               last_name: "test",
                               password: "123",
                               password_confirmation: "123",
                               roles: ["admin"])
```